# Text Editor With Both Text and Equation

Tags: nicedit, formula-editor

I am using java struts 2. I need a text editor which should have text editor and also equation. I tried to integrate nicedit with wiris. http://www.wiris.com/plugins/docs/nicedit By looking at their documentation I could not find a solution. I don't find any app folder when the war is deployed.

I have been trying for a while to do this, but I can't find any open source. Please recommend any new plugin which has both or how to implement in wiris

Answer (score 1):

We understand you mean `pluginwiris_engine/app`. Please note that if you are installing NicEdit plugin for Java you need two components `nicedit_wiris` directory and `pluginwiris_engine.war` (also included in the plugin package). Once pluginwiris_engine.war is deployed it will automatically create the `pluginwiris_engine/app/*` path.
We would also recommend that you download our simple integration demo from http://www.wiris.com/plugins/docs/demo-download (look for NicEdit).

Comment: I deployed the pluginwiris_engine and I don't find any app folder inside. Also I tried to put the nicedit_wiris folder inside the webapp. I need to know how its gonna help me in integrating. As I am new to java I don't understand your process. If I deploy your war then how will I add that in my app. Please give me step by step instruction, so that it will be useful.

Comment: 1.- Download nicedit_wiris from http://www.wiris.com/plugins3/nicedit/download (the directory is inside the zip package).
2.- Place nicedit_wiris inside your NicEdit installation directory (nicedit_wiris directory should be next to nicEdit.js). 
3.- Deploy pluginwiris_engine.war (included in the package download in step 1).
4.- Once the war is deployed you can test the plugin installation browsing http://<domain>:<port>/pluginwiris_engine/app/test
5.- The rest of the steps related to NicEdit configuration are at step 4 in http://www.wiris.com/en/plugins/docs/nicedit

Comment: If you want to install the integration demo:
1.- Download WIRIS Plugin for NicEdit and Java - DEMO from http://www.wiris.com/plugins/docs/demo-download
2.- Copy the full directory into your webapps directory
3.- Deploy pluginwiris_engine.war included inside the downloaded demo package.

Comment: I don't find app folder inside pluginwiris_engine. I only find core,docs,lang, META-INF and WEB-INF

Comment: There is no app folder inside pluginwiris_engine, this directory is defined in the application web.xml. You can simply open that path in your browser.

Comment: I tried opening http://localhost:8080/pluginwiris_engine/app/test.html. But its showing status 404 error. Please help.

Comment: The test path, as detailed above, does not include .html